# How do you use a custom Machine learning model on flutter?

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I and my friend are working on an app that is supposed to use an Machine learning model he created. This model features facial recognition on a camera stream. Based on a sample he showed me, running the model on his pc,
whenever a face is spotted it marks the whole face and its features i.e the eyes, the mouth e.t.c

Now I would like to know how to achieve this on flutter the way it was in the sample he showed me. Some
of the examples I found online mostly utilizes ML kit which from what i've learnt so far uses already available
models.

So can anyone point me in the right direction as to how am to achieve this? Any resource at all or detailed
answer would really be cool.

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: @molbdnilo Noted.

Comment: There are a few Flutter binding for TFLite. e.g. https://pub.dev/packages/tflite and https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter

Comment: Thanks, @Tiezhen. Do you know if those packages support analyzing CameraStreams (able to process image frames)?